# LM2576-ADJ Unstable Output

Tags: voltage-regulator

I've designed simple power supply with LM2576-ADJ for 12 V input and 5.35 V output at 3.0 A load.

Problems:

1- Output voltage changes rapidly and peak to peak is around 950 mV.

2- Output voltage drop to 4.10 V with 4 ohm load.

Schematic:
[image: Schematic]

PCB:
[image: PCB]

Peak to peak with minimum load: 941 mV

Peak to peak with 4 ohm load: 620 mV

Pin2 output minimum load:
[image: Pin2 output minimum load]

Pin2 output 70 ohm load:
[image: Pin2 output 70ohm load]

Pin2 output 4 ohm load:
[image: Pin2 output 4ohm load]

Output minimum load:
[image: Output minimum load]

Output 4 ohm load:
[image: Output 4ohm load]

Comment: Please write down which picture for what output current is taken.

Comment: L1 is the problem I bet - please supply a data sheet link.

Comment: @TodorSimeonov Sorry I've added title to images

Comment: @Andyaka Here is the inductor : http://www.tme.eu/gb/details/dpu068a5/toroidal-tht-inductors/talema/dpo-50-68/

Comment: Inductor type is OK, maybe 68uH value is low, but it depends on what is your nominal current. A common method is to calculate it for current ripple less than 40% of nominal peak to peak. If nominal current is 1.33A (4ohm) then dI < 0.53A, inductance shall be at least 115uH.

Comment: It sounds like you want up to 16 watts delivered to your load. With a 50 kHz switching frequency you need to transfer about 300 uJ per cycle. What does the inductor spec tell you?

Comment: @TodorSimeonov Thank you for suggestion I've used this calculator for component selection and inductor value : http://www.nomad.ee/micros/lm2576/index.shtml , Also I've checked many different value of inductors up to 330 uH before asking question in SO with no success.

Comment: @Andyaka In the datasheet they mentioned energy storage 850uJ but no frequency. Is this what you've asked?

Comment: Yeah that sounds fine. I take it back about the inductor!

Comment: @sDev you can take a look at this online calculator/simulator - http://schmidt-walter-schaltnetzteile.de/smps_e/smps_e.html - it is very useful for basic SMPS topoligies and also explains the theory/maths behind the calculations.

Comment: @TodorSimeonov Very interesting website, Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With 100uH inductor, 52kHz switching freq., 12V to 5.35V conversion and 1.33A output current (4 ohm load) your inductor's current will go 0.6A peak-to-peak. Be sure your capacitors are Low ESR and able to handle at least 0.3A RMS current.

I see some major issues with your layout design. I don't think they will result in 1V p-p, but I think you should consider them to design a good DC-DC converter.

1) This schematic has only 1 sensitive node - the feedback divider and you have placed it right under the inductor when magnetic field is strongest. Move it somewhere else.

2) The ground connection for R1 should be taken alone from the closest low impedance capacitor - the ceramic one will be better. You take it from diode's anode where pulsed current flows.

3) The output voltage connection for R3 - same thing - noise from inductor.

4) The ground connection of the switching IC - 2576 - too far away from output's filter capacitors.

When designing SMPS first you must examine well where the largest pulsed current flows. You should keep these traces as shortest as possible. The ground pin of the control IC must be as close as possible to input and output capacitors' grounds. The feedback and any low current signal must be taken from a low impedance source with highest possible filtration. Making "star points" near capacitors and powering different nodes with different traces is better.

Think of the copper on the board as a resistor, not just the "ideal short"!

Comment: Thank you for valuable answer, I'll follow your leads and redraw the PCB then come back to you with result.

Comment: I've followed your leads and redraw PCB the output ripple dropped to 300mV peek to peek but the voltage still drop to 4 V with 4ohm load from 5.35 V, I've changed inductor to 500uH without any success. So the voltage drop problem still exist

Comment: @sDev did you get your problem figured out?